# Hitting time Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

How can we compute the probability that Brownian motion hits $b$ before $a$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Brownian motion is a martingale so you can apply the [Optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem). If $t$ is the first hitting time of $a$ or $b$, then, 
$$
0 = \mathbb{E}[X_0] = \mathbb{E}[X_t] = ap_a + bp_b
$$
Can you finish it now?

Comment: could you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: @KlaraYitsovich please ask more specifically. Do you know of the Optional stopping theorem? Can you apply it? Or do you have trouble finishing the problem?

Comment: I don’t know of the optional stopping theorem. Is it the only way to compute the required probability?

Comment: @KlaraYitsovich I don't know of any easy ways. Do you know the reflection principle? Can you derive the distribution of the hitting time of $a$? If so, may consider random variables $T_a, T_b$ (hitting times of $a$ and $b$) and play wit how they may depend on each other...

Comment: @KlaraYitsovich Here is [some related discussion](https://galton.uchicago.edu/~yibi/teaching/stat317/2014/Lectures/Lecture23_6up.pdf), feel free to Google around for more.

Comment: Thanks for your help!